# Adding Intent Filters to Xamarin Forms / Xamarin Android Errors

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am building a Home Launcher App with Xamarin Forms, something like the Niagara Launcher.

To make my app actually behave like a launcher app I want to add the needed intent Filters to my mainactivity.cs in the android project, according to this post:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21961/creating-an-android-launcher-home-screen-using-xamarin

Making it to look like this:

```
    namespace Launcher.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Launcher", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionMain }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

For every Intent Filter I get an errror Telling me

- Static member 'member' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

and

- Static member 'member' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead.

I am new to Xamarin and would be very glad about a hint / direction what I am doing wrong. Thank you guys

Comment: Which usings do you have? What happens if you for fun just replace the `Intent.*` fields with a string? Does it still complain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Static member 'member' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Since your `member` is static you should use the class/type name to access it, not the instance/variable name.Using the `Class.Func` method.

If your form class is named ClassA, do this `ClassA.member`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing a using statement

`using Android.Content;`